# Symlink and its target produce different behaviors?

Tags: symlink, path

When I run `npm`, I get this output:

```
-bash: /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

When I run `which -a npm`, I get this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

When I run `ls -a /usr/local/bin/npm`, I get this output:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  38 Jan 29 14:02 /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

At this point, my ability to understand what's happening goes off the rails. If I'm not mistaken, that's telling me I have a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. So I went to that directory and ran `./npm-cli.js`, and it worked correctly. I was expecting it to give the same output as the initial command up above, which seems to be symlinked to it, but it did not. It functioned normally.

Why would these have different behaviors? What am I missing? I am trying to troubleshoot so that my `npm` works correctly again.

Comment: `type -a npm` will likely be more instructive than `which -a npm`

Comment: In this case, same output-- `npm is /usr/local/bin/npm`

Comment: That `No such file or directory` error is also printed when the interpreter (either shebang of a script or dynamic loader of a binary) is not found. What is the first line of the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` file?

Comment: Yeah, it has a shebang. `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Comment: And what does happen when you run `node` from your current directory?

Comment: Whoa, crazy, node works and now npm works. Unclear which dir I was in when it didn't work. Also unclear why it would work in some dirs and not others. There is only one node installed, at `/usr/local/bin/node`. I have to mess around with this further. But now I have meetings, sigh.